# array is empty after pushing object into it Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I want to push `{ "studentid": achecked[index].value }` this into a array, but if i push it my array is like this `(2) [{…}, {…}]` and not my checkbox value.

this is my code:

```js
 var achecked = $("form input:checkbox:checked");
var values = [];
achecked.each(function (index) {
    var student = { "studentid": achecked[index].value };
    values.push(student);
});
console.log(values);

var postdata = {
    'displayname': $("#displayname").val(),
    'email': $("#email").val(),
    'students': [
    ]
};
postdata.students = values;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toevoegen" value="10" />
<button class="btn btn-success" id="aanmaken">Aanmaken</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

does someone knows and could help me?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the `{...}` in your console log output?

Comment: @OKsure Yes it's empty, it show the same...

Comment: Would you add in the snippet some example of the checkboxes?

Comment: check  achecked length

Comment: I think the issue may be that you have no form element but your selector is looking for one.

Comment: @OKsure If I console log `{ "studentid": achecked[index].value }` it shows the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working for me. Not sure what your HTML looks like, but the selector `form input:checkbox:checked` will require a form around all the checkboxes.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var achecked = $("form input:checkbox:checked");
  var values = [];
  achecked.each(function (index) {
      var student = { "studentid": achecked[index].value };
      values.push(student);
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" checked value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="5" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```